# Visual Studio 2012 - Activate on delete cascade

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating some tables using a Local based database in Visual Studio and I have 2 tables : DBAppointment (parent) and DBPatient (child).

What I'm trying to do is to specify the on delete cascade action (so when I'm deleting a record from the child table, the parent table record containing the id of the child table record should be removed) but I can't really find where this option is.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Read this Microsoft article first. Read Me. I use the GUI during design so here is a picture of how it is selected in SSMS. [image]

The syntax added to the foreign key is " ON DELETE CASCADE "

Hope this will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Entity Framework with Code First Approach in your EfContext you can set `.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);`

See [Working With Cascade Delete](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html)